# extract text from images programmatically

Tags: image, text, ocr

I am looking for a programmatic way to retrieve text on the images . I am not aware of any such tool if available already. I need to download the images first and then extract text from them . Is there any programmatic way to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Tesseract OCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) can extract text from images. What exactly do you mean by *extract*?

Comment: by extract I meant // I have a button image whose text is like"Click Here" so i need to extract just teh text "Click here" from button image.

Answer (score 2):

OCR is a complex technology (image segmentation, angle correction, binarization, characters segmentation, analysis of combined and broken characters, dictionary checking, etc), but there are ready-to-use OCR engines, most of them are commercial, for instance:

- Most accurate (and expensive + royalty) - Abby OCR engine.
- Good accuracy (royalty) - OmniPage OCR engine.
- Good accuracy (royalty-free) - Nicomsoft CrystalOCR engine.
- Acceptable accuracy (free) - Tesseract OCR engine.