# How to extract text from a CAPTCHA image in Objective-C for a Mac OS X Application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, captcha

I am developing one Mac OS X Application which has a concept of reading/extracting text from a CAPTCHA image. I searched on google and got an API named "DeathByCaptcha", which does exactly what I want to do but this API is not for Mac OS X, this API is available for .Net/C/PHP/Python etc..

'DeathByCaptcha' can be found on the web [here](http://www.deathbycaptcha.com/user/login).
I found [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373949/extract-text-from-images-programmatically) while searching  but this does not read a CAPTCHA image, it just reads a simple image and convert into text.

Please help me extract text From a CAPTCHA image using Objective-C for a Mac OS X Application.

Comment: If it supports C then you can use it without problem.  Perhaps create your own Objective-C wrapper around their C API and then submit your changes back to them in the spirit of Open Source.

Comment: how to create wrapper for CAPTCHA in Objective-C ? I am getting CAPTCHA image only the thing is remaining extracting it's Text from the captcha. Please tell me the startup point for creating Wrapper ?

Comment: He means make a class that will interact and parse the data required into an objective-c objects, etc. from the c library (and vice versa). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C.

Comment: trojanfoe, BooRanger,  If library is in c language then it will definitely should have to work for iOS, as per definition of objective-C language.

Comment: @iHungry Didn't I already state that?  BooRanger also seems to understand that, as does Abizern, so what exactly is your point?

Comment: @iHungry ya of course dude were just saying make it neater for yourself and use a wrapper but it will work straight out of the box.

Comment: I don't have knowledge/experience in Creating Wrapper ! how i start working on it ?

Comment: @iHungry I am creating app for MAC OS bro... not for iOS !!

Comment: It's not possible to help you any further as we cannot see their C API, as you need to be a customer to see it.  Forget my comment about submitting anything you create back to them, as they are not open source, so screw 'em.  If you can post roughly how it works, we might be able to provide some rough examples of wrapping it in ObjC.

Comment: @trojanfoe Sure I am providing you rough idea what exactly needs ! just give me 10 min.

Comment: @HelpingHand, dude you can use this library for MacOs app also, Because mac app also made up using objective-C pure cocoa framework, i suggest you need to understand first proper hierarchy and structure of Mac app , objective-C language and how to handle C API incorporate with os app.

Comment: It's impossible to help without knowing the semantics of their API.  For example does it use a session key? If so how is this created and destroyed? Do you need to provide a customer ID?  What data types do the calls use? Ad infinitum.

Comment: I already have Server CAPTCHA Image(which generates when we SignUp on Facebook) in an UIImage Object, now from this image i need to get "TEXT" which is written in it for identifying Machine or Human ! @trojanfoe

Comment: We seem to be going around in circles. I know what the requirements are for a CAPTCHA parser but I cannot help you with the C API provided by *Death By CAPTCHA* until you show it to me.

Comment: @trojanfoe I got DeathByCaptcha C API, please download it from here : http://www.screencast.com/t/2MZ6QcJU38x . Let me know your views about this DeathByCaptcha C API to integrate in MAC OS application . Waiting for your reply ...

Comment: @trojanfoe I integrated DeathByCaptcha "C" API in XCode in my project to solve Captcha problem but it is looking like it's for windows. have a look on Screenshot to understand my issue : http://screencast.com/t/D8jYxeK0w

How to proceed with it now ? please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hi all, I wrote below code to solve my captcha issue and it worked fantastic for me.***

***Code For Reading Text From Captcha Image***

You will need ASIHTTPRequest API to send HTTP Request on web and get response for the below code.

Import respective classes of ASIHTTPRequest API into your class where you are going to do process for fetching text from captcha image.

Now use below method and call to solve catpcha .

```
-(NSString *)CaptchaToText 
{
    // Captcha Image Url in NSData object
    NSData *urlData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://oi47.tinypic.com/357hyea.jpg"]];

    // base64 image data
    NSString *imageBase64Data = [ASIHTTPRequest base64forData:urlData ];

    //NSString *imageBase64Data =[self base64EncodedString:urlData];
    NSLog(@"imageBase64Data =%@\n\n",imageBase64Data);

    // prefix - base64 image data
    NSString *prefixBase64Data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"base64:%@",imageBase64Data];
    NSLog(@"prefixBase64Data Value = %@\n\n",prefixBase64Data);

    ASIHTTPRequest *req=[ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://oi47.tinypic.com/357hyea.jpg"]];

    [req startSynchronous];
    NSError *err=[req error];

    if(!err){
        NSString *respo=[req responseString];
        NSLog(@"respo= %@",respo);

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.dbcapi.me/api/captcha"];

        ASIFormDataRequest *request=[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

        [request setPostValue:@"YourDeathByCaptchaUserName" forKey:@"username"];
        [request setPostValue:@"YourDeathByCaptchaPassword!@#$" forKey:@"password"];
        [request setPostValue:prefixBase64Data forKey:@"captchafile"];

        [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
        [request startSynchronous];

        NSError *error=[request error];

        if(!error){

            // Here we will get "Text" data from Captcha Image in "response"
            NSString *response=[request responseString];
            NSLog(@"response= %@",response);
            }
        else{
            NSLog(@"error= %@",error);
            }

        }
    else{
        NSLog(@"err= %@",err);
        }

    return response;
}
```

That's it. DONE

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the API, turns out you first need to build the library.

1. Open a terminal, navigate to the dbc_api_v4_2_c folder and type

   make

You should get a new folder called lib containing the libdeathbycaptcha.so library file.

1. Now, create a new Xcode project, include the library in your resources, add the deathbycaptcha.h header to your project.
2. Then you can use the code provided in the example, but only the code that is not for windows. For instance :

   ```
   void *lib = dlopen("./libdeathbycaptcha.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   if (!lib) {
       fprintf(stderr, "dlopen(): %s\n", dlerror());
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   dbc_init = (void *)GetProcAddress(lib, "dbc_init");
   dbc_close = (void *)GetProcAddress(lib, "dbc_close");
   dbc_get_balance = (void *)GetProcAddress(lib, "dbc_get_balance");
   dbc_decode_file = (void *)GetProcAddress(lib, "dbc_decode_file");
   dbc_report = (void *)GetProcAddress(lib, "dbc_report");
   dbc_close_captcha = (void *)GetProcAddress(lib, "dbc_close_captcha");
   ```

It should compile fine. Don't forget to include the following headers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <dlfcn.h> // not in the docs, but required for dlsym
#include "deathbycaptcha.h"
```

In addition, you may also need to install the Xcode command line tools (in Xcode preferences) if you haven't already done so.

Comment: yeah, I integrated DeathByCaptcha-C api in XCode in my existing project.
The DeathByCaptcha-C api file extensions are .h and .c NOT .m 
What to do in this case. It seem the API is for WINDOWS.
please have a look on screenshot error which arise after integrating DeathByCaptcha-C api : http://screencast.com/t/D8jYxeK0w

Please give me some advice in this case. Waiting for your reply @Jean

Comment: you can find Sample source code with DeathByCaptcha api integrated in it here : http://www.screencast.com/users/TauseefKhan/folders/Default/media/2455cad4-7cd8-449a-b285-61b72269cbe1

please check and let me know how i can proceed with this and if it is not possible using this api then any idea how i can solve Captcha issue programatically for Mac os apps ! Special thanks for your instant reply.. @Jean

Comment: @NSExpression Thanks. Looks like you have to build it as a library first. Then you can use the API. Go with the terminal into your dbc_api_v4_2_c directory. Type make. You will get a nice libdeathbycaptcha.so library that you can then use in your project.

Comment: I did the same and got DeathByCaptcha.so file, now how to process with it ? 
you can see the .so file here : http://screencast.com/t/LN8auZ7LwCkQ
I know how to use api but don't know from this point what to do ! plzz help me Jean @Jean

Comment: Now, you need to add the .so file and the deathbycaptcha.h to your project. Once you compile the project, the .so file will be added to your resources. When calling dlopen(…) you need to use the path provided by NSBundle ([[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"libdeathbycaptcha" ofType:@"so"]) in order to load the library. See my answer for more instructions.

Comment: Okay, am trying the way like what you said... will let you know in an hour. Thanks a lot

Comment: Not Worked Bro...Trying using CURL tool. i:e Using DeathByCaptcha-php api
The process is like we will place DBC-php api on our server and get url from server and pass parameters to DBC-php api class from Browser then our server will sent request to DBC server and get response from them and then will pass response to our browser . Lets see what happens but this solution is provided by DeathByCaptcha team for Mac OS application, so it must work . Thanks for followup (bow) 
 @Jean

Comment: I'm sorry to read that. What failed ? I guess their solution should work. I saw their website that they did help their customers with integrating their API.

Comment: I did more read on DeathByCaptcha site as you said... here give some explanation on that site about using api command line . have a look into this may this clear my doubt after reading by you.
link : http://pastebin.com/MzxsR5U3

please suggest me what i can do with this ! thanks @Jean

Comment: I read the text you posted and I believe that the easiest approach by far is to use the solution I provided above. Just compile their library and integrate it into your app. The second-best approach would be to use the solution they provide at the bottom of your text : 1.Upload your CAPTCHA in a POSTed multipart/form-data; 2. Polling for your CAPTCHA status using a get request, and they will provide you with the info as soon as it is solved.

Comment: Yeah, the second solution i found as best and trying that one . @Jean

Thanks for everything Jean, you Deserve for the Bounty. :)